# How to access repeating subtree in ANTLR4 through visitor?

Tags: antlr4

I can't believe that I am the first man to ask this question! When using ANTLR4, I need a visitor to walk through the parse tree and make some modifications, so I need to access the subtrees within each tree node. Here is a snippet of my Fortran grammar:

```
ifStatement
    : IF_KEYWORD expression
      ( ( THEN_KEYWORD
          executableStatement*
          elseIfStatement*  // <--- problem is here
          elseStatement?
          END_KEYWORD IF_KEYWORD
        ) | executableStatement )
    ;

elseIfStatement
    : ELSE_KEYWORD IF_KEYWORD expression THEN_KEYWORD executableStatement*
    ;
```

As you can see, there is repeating subtree `elseIfStatement` in `ifStatement`. When I create a visitor for the parse tree, I want to access the contexts of all the `elseIfStatement` that are parsed:

```
public Void visitIfStatement(FortranParser.IfStatementContext ctx) {
    ...
    for (FortranParser.ElseIfStatementContext elsIf : ctx.elseIfStatement()) // ERROR!!!
        visitElseIfStatement(elseIf);
    ...
    return null;
}
```

But `ctx.elseIfStatement()` only returns the first occurrence of `elseIfStatement` as:

```
if (a == 1) then
    a = 2
else if (b == 1) then |
    b = 3             | -> returned by ctx.elseIfStatement()
else if (c == 1) then \
    c = 4             \ -> ignored??
else
    d = 4
end if
```

So how to access all the `elseIfStatement` subtrees? And this question applies to all the parser rule pattern with '*' as `executableStatement*` above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a bug, if I remove the `| executableStatement` alternative, `ctx.elseIfStatement()` *does* return a `List<ElseIfStatementContext>`. You might want to report it: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

However, as you're doing it now, you'll be forced to do some `null` checks to see which of the alternatives matched. A nicer way would be to ["label" your alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565794/antlr-4-tree-inject-rewrite-operator):

```
ifStatement
 : IF_KEYWORD expression
   THEN_KEYWORD
   executableStatement* 
   elseIfStatement*  
   elseStatement? END_KEYWORD IF_KEYWORD     #ifMultipleStatements
 | IF_KEYWORD expression executableStatement #ifSingleStatement
 ;
```

which will generate the following:

```
public static class IfMultipleStatementsContext extends IfStatementContext {
    ...
    public List<ElseIfStatementContext> elseIfStatement() {
        return getRuleContexts(ElseIfStatementContext.class);
    }
    ...
}
```

I.e.: it generates the proper amount of `ElseIfStatementContext`s.

Comment: Bart, thanks for helping! I followed your advice, and also got `public List<ElseIfStatementContext> elseIfStatement()` in `class IfMultipleStatementsContext`. I think ANTLR4 does not like my previous rule style? I will report this issue anyway.

Comment: I have another question. Since we have labeled the alternative rules, if we have another rule contains `ifStatement`, then how do we get down to `ifMultipleStatements` or `ifSingleStatement`. I see none of them in `IfStatementContext` class.

Comment: @LiDong, I didn't test it, but I guess you'd cast the `IfStatementContext` to either a `IfMultipleStatementsContext` or `IfSingleStatementContext`.

Comment: How do I know which one should I cast? By checking some subtrees' existence? Thanks!

Comment: @LiDong, I think you'd need a (not so pretty) `instanceof` on the `IfStatementContext` before casting.