# ANTLR: how to linearize/flatten a tree-structure?

Tags: parsing, antlr, transformation, lexer

I need to transform text from following structure:

```
{ A1 A2 { B1 B2 { C1 C2 } } }
```

to the following developed/flattened structure:

```
{ A1 }
{ A2 B1 }
{ A2 B2 C1 }
{ A2 B2 C2 }
```

I use the following Antlr grammar to parse the file:

```
grammar tree;
node : '{' (STRING | node)* '}';
STRING : ('A' .. 'Z' | '0' .. '9')+;
WS : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r') -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Is it possible to perform the Ast transformation by only using inline Antlr rewrite rules (using `->`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at `channel(HIDDEN)`, it seems you're using ANTLR4, which does not have the rewrite functionality anymore: [ANTLR 4 tree inject/rewrite operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565794/antlr-4-tree-inject-rewrite-operator). Besides, if you'd be using ANTLR3, I doubt you'd be able to rewrite the AST is such a way.

You should see this as two operations: 1) parse the input, and 2) walk/visit the parse tree and [by using plain programming] rewrite the parsed tree into something else. This last step is done by yourself in tree listener- or visitor of which ANTLR generates base classes for.

Comment: Thanks. The grammar is not exactly the one I use, it was just an example to give an idea of the composite model. I have indeed already implemented the transformation in the same way as you described: with a visitor implemented in C#. I'm curious to see whether it is possible to "develop" the tree with a smart rewrite rule... and without visitor... Any other suggestion?

Comment: @jrg, as I said: ANTLR4 does not have any way to rewrite its (parse) tree, only ANTLR3 does. And with ANTLR3, I highly doubt it would be possible: rewrite rules are more meant to remove, or make small alterations to nodes in the tree, not to radically change it as you describe.